# scala - How to call public static method defined in Java from Scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying call `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter#forPattern` method.

But following seems not working.

```
scala> import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

scala> DateTimeFormatter.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")
<console>:30: error: value forPattern is not a member of object org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
       DateTimeFormatter.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")
                         ^
```

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java - Scala interoperability works as expected in such scenarios. You just messed up the class names probably. There is no `DateTimeFormatter#forPattern` according to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) but there is `DateTimeFormat#forPattern`.

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")
```

works like a charm.

Comment: @battaio Thanks a lot.